# Need assistance on scheduled jobs

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, delete, scheduled-job, cron

I have a scheduled job in my org which was scheduled 2 years ago without an end date. It runs every Friday at a specific time, which means it was scheduled using a cron expression. If I delete that scheduled job directly will it be aborted? Or else should it be aborted with some code?

Comment: You can schedule for every Friday at a specific time through the UI. The scheduling pattern you describe by no means indicates a cron expression had to be used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Deleting the scheduled job is enough. It will not run again.

You can also delete using code.

```
for (CronTrigger ct : [SELECT Id FROM CronTrigger WHERE CreatedBy.Name='xxx']) {
    System.abortJob(ct.Id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @sfdcFanBoy....I just wanted to know...if i delete scheduled job directly....it will not create any problem in the future right?

Comment: @learner_sfdc : No worries - deleting the scheduled job from the UI or code will not cause any issues.

Comment: @Learner_sfdc Yes, that won't be a problem!